# datetime.utcnow() is off by 1 Hour

Tags: python, datetime

Why is utcnow off by 1 hour??

Code:

```
from datetime import *
print datetime.utcnow()
```

result:

```
2016-11-25 10:28:04.655978
```

Servertime:

```
Fri Nov 25 11:28:11 CET 2016
```

Comment: Well, UTC and CET are one hour apart.

Comment: DST is enable in your app but not in the server.

Comment: @RaphaelMoita It's not about Daylight Savings. It's November. It's about Central Europe being an hour east of London.

Comment: @PeterWood is right. I didn't realize that server was CET referenced. http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/utc-to-cet-converter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because CET is UTC + 1

Check this link to see the conversion:
http://www.worldtimebuddy.com/utc-to-cet-converter

Comment: Thanks, I had the issue with suds. it's using utc by default for timestamps. had to edit out the utc there.

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.utcnow()` returns UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) time : [UTC Time definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

To get the same time as your server use `datetime.now()`.

```
In [8]: from datetime import datetime

In [9]: datetime.utcnow()
Out[9]: datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 25, 10, 32, 18, 288195)

In [10]: datetime.now()
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 25, 11, 32, 22, 336213)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happened because your server in different time zone. (CET = +1)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 25, 10, 35, 33, 931951)
>>>
```

use `pytz` module to change timezone

```
pip install pytz
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use timezone like

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"

# Current time in UTC
now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
print now_utc.strftime(fmt)

# Convert to US/Pacific time zone
now_pacific = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific'))
print now_pacific.strftime(fmt)

# Convert to Europe/Berlin time zone
now_berlin = now_pacific.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Berlin'))
print now_berlin.strftime(fmt)
```